# Modifying a column to contain Unique Character Combinations

Tags: r, unique, distinct, tidyverse

I have a problem where I need to find unique flight tail numbers in the nycflights13 data set. Then, I need to find the tailnum with the largest number of unique destinations in any of the airports in the data set.

I have tried including unique to tailnum as a column, or defining tailnum as distinct before putting it in my pipe, but none seem to work.

```
flights %>%
    count(tailnum, dest) %>%
    arrange(-n) %>%
    na.omit(tailnum_new) %>%
    print()
```

This code gives me a table with the plane's tail number, destination, and how many times that tailnum flew from that location, but I only want unique observations in my tailnum variable. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do

```
library(dplyr)
flights %>%
   filter(complete.cases(tailnum)) %>%
   group_by(tailnum) %>% 
   summarise(n = n_distinct(dest)) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   slice(which.max(n))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  tailnum     n
#  <chr>   <int>
#1 N11194     47
```

Comment: Appreciate the quick response; does the complete.cases line remove things like NAs? Then summarise is able to find distinct flights?

Comment: @PageSim It is similar to `!is.na(tailnum)`.  Here, we group by 'tailnum' and get the number of distinct element of 'dest' and `slice` to find the `max` number of 'dest'(which I think is your description of expected output)

Answer (score 0):

```
flights %>%
    filter(!is.na(tailnum)) %>%
    count(tailnum, dest) %>%
    count(tailnum, sort = TRUE) %>%
    slice(1)
## A tibble: 1 x 2
#  tailnum     n
#  <chr>   <int>
#1 N11194     47
```